# What is the best way to parse application/json Jersey @Consumes MIME type in Java?

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, jax-rs

As the question states, what would be the best way for my Jersey webapp to consume JSON on POST requests with the @Consumes annotation and then save it to a variable? 
My method is like this:

```
@Path("/postask")
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("text/plain")
public String postAsk(@Context ServletContext context) {
    return Chatbot.ask(someinputgottenfrommyjson, context);
}
```

I know that there is only one String input going to my Chatbot method and I can use the text/plain type but that is irrelevant. I am doing this for future expansion.
My application will recieve a JSON string that looks somewhat like `{ "input": "Some Text Input provided by the client" }` and I need to get that input field and save it to a variable. 
From looking at other answers and tutorials, it appears one way to do this is to create a class that reflects the fields in your JSON object and Jersey parses into the object automatically. Maybe I am wrong about this. I do not like this approach because it will create bulky classes. Another way is to probably use form parameters but I am not sure if this will work. Is there an easy way to do this?
Sorry if my question is stupid, I have never worked with Jersey or Java web apps before.

Comment: What's wrong with _bulky classes_? Any code you might write to parse a JSON document as a string is likely be more verbose and harder to understand than a simple parameter class. If you're worried about performance, implement the code in the most simple way possible, get some numbers and prove that it's actually to slow for your need. Readable code should be easy to make faster but it rarely works the other way round.

Comment: @toniedzweidz ok thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to get around making DAOs. You can have your method take a String and then parse it to a org.json.JSONObject.